# How to do regex for customized nginx logs

Tags: regex, nginx, fail2ban

I want to implement fail2ban for our webapp. The problem is that i dont know how to deal with the regex.
our nginx logs looks like this

```
[REM-ADD]:"172.16.2.148" - [REQ-TIME]:"26/Apr/2016:12:05:32 +0530" -[STATUS]:"200" - [CLIENTIP]:"125.19.65.202, 54.239.168.59" - [CONNECTION]:"489" - [CONN-REQ]:"6" - [CONTENT-LEN]:"-" - [REQ-LEN]:"673" - [BODY-BYTE]:"1090" - [USER-AGENT]:"-" - [REQ]:"GET /news/api/v1/app_settings/ HTTP/1.1" - [REQ-BODY]:"-" - 
[REM-ADD]:"172.16.0.100" - [REQ-TIME]:"26/Apr/2016:12:05:35 +0530" -[STATUS]:"200" - [CLIENTIP]:"125.19.65.202, 54.239.168.60" - [CONNECTION]:"513" - [CONN-REQ]:"1" - [CONTENT-LEN]:"-" - [REQ-LEN]:"673" - [BODY-BYTE]:"1090" - [USER-AGENT]:"-" - [REQ]:"GET /news/api/v1/app_settings/ HTTP/1.1" - [REQ-BODY]:"
```

now fail2ban docs says for example `nginx-noscript.conf`

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*GET.*(\.php|\.asp|\.exe|\.pl|\.cgi|\scgi)
ignoreregex =
```

Basically I want to ask how to format the regex for my custom nginx logs.
I tried some regex but it dosent work and does not throw any error as well.

Comment: shouldn't it be `\.scgi`?

Comment: @rock321987 was referring this http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/554-how-to-secure-an-nginx-server-with-fail2ban

Answer (score 0):

Specify a log format compatible with Apache's combined format

```
log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"' ;
```

It will be easier to deal with